# How using javascript (no jquery) to retrieve all markup between two tags into a string

Tags: javascript, html

Assuming a screen element has been selected using something like const foo = document.getElementById("foo") I'd like to retrieve all markup between that elements tags `<div id="foo">...</div>`

The issue I find is it only returns me one level in the dom tree. Is there a way to retrieve **all** markup? ie. for `<div id="foo"> <ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li></ul></div>`

Comment: Have you tried `foo.outerHTML`?

Comment: `.getElementById("#foo")` is wrong; it should be simply "foo", not "#foo"

Comment: Apologies @Pointy - fixed. Doesnt solve the question though :)

Comment: Well as noted in the first comment, `.outerHTML` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
const foo = document.getElementById("foo");
const markup = foo.outerHTML;
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately only returns the first child element - and not the elements nested inside that child element.

Comment: @user1517566 no, that is not correct. The `outerHTML` will return the entire content of the element.

Comment: hmm. interesting. I am testing and there is a nested <div><svg>....</svg></div> that is not being returned using outerHTML

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, why you're saying outerHTML only returns the first child.
Providing a snippet below showing it returns the entire dom structure including the queried element.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector("#parent");

const requiredDomTree = parent.outerHTML;
console.log(requiredDomTree)
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li><span>deep nested</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort here! Im not achieving the result you're demonstrating, but perhaps I need to find a different way to address my challenge.  Thank you!

Comment: @user1517566 You may want to add more details to your question and possibly reproduce your issue if possible